# What is the latest way to get the direction user is facing wrt earth's true north and rotate the heading arrow on google map in android?

Tags: android, android-sensors, google-maps-android-api-3

I am new to android development and I am trying to build an app for learning purposes. I have used the Google maps sdk 3.0 inside a fragment and implemented fusedlocationclient api successfully. Now I downloaded DevCheck app and saw the orientation sensor showing readings in degress. I want to -

1) obtain the angle between geographic north and the direction user is facing

2) Rotate the blue dot arrow on the map accordingly.

I am confused as I could not find any updated solution. Could someone guide me!

Talking about this blue dot which is currently pointing towards wrong direction
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFoZp.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide any screenshots/video of what you are describing?

Comment: Provided an image link for reference as I am not yet allowed to post images due to rep points